# Using dbatools powershell module with azure automation hybird worker groups

Tags: sql-server, automation, dbatools, azure-sql-server, iaas

We want to use dbatools powershell module with azure automation . We already have dbatools module on hybird worker group machines . We tested the code we want to run by directly logging into the hybird worker group machine and it works as expected but the same code when it is run from inside azure automation runbook it gives error around credentials . Do we need to import the dbatools module to azure automation account ? Has any one used dbatools with azure automation account hybird worker  to run dbatools commands against azure IaaS VMs? Thanks for your help